# How to plot with dtaidistance

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, dtw

I tried an [example](https://dtaidistance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/dtw.html) using dtaidistance and dtw, but it did not plot the result.

```
from dtaidistance import dtw
from dtaidistance import dtw_visualisation as dtwvis
import numpy as np
s1 = np.array([0., 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0])
s2 = np.array([0., 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0])
path = dtw.warping_path(s1, s2)
dtwvis.plot_warping(s1, s2, path, filename="warp.png")
```

It should have looked like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, it did not show up.

I tried to add "`plt.show()`" at the end of the code (previously importing pyplot of course). But, in this case, it has not helped.

What is the reason it does not plot the graph, like in the example above?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the filename, then you can reach the output with plt.show()

```
figure, axes = dtwvis.plot_warping(s1, s2, path)

figure.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The picture in the example is not meant to be plotted within python but saved as .png to hard drive where the python code is stored.